# Laravel Eager loading with() function returns empty array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm using eager loading and with() function on Laravel 8.

In my model, I have this relationship :

```
public function gba_populations()
{
    return $this->hasManyJson(GbaPopulation::class, 'nct_numbers[]->nct_number', 'nct_id');
}
```

And in my controller, I try to get my data through the with() function :

```
$query->with(['gba_populations' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('patient_population_title', 'gba_addition_benefits_gba_added_benefit_id_text', 'nct_numbers');
}])
```

This query returns an empty array gba_populations: []

But when I call my relationship like this :

```
NctsInfo::find(3)->gba_populations
```

It works... How is it possible ?

Can you help me ?

Thank you for your help

Jérémy

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your database and/or the models

Comment: You need to include `nct_id` in your `select()`, otherwise it will have no idea how to eager load it, so `$query->select('nct_id', 'patient_population_title', ...);`